# call constructors by using bracket syntax in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

As you know,you can access properties and methods in two ways:

```
dot syntax: object.property=value;
```

&

```
bracket syntax: object["property"]=value; or object["property"]=["value];
```

The bracket syntax also works for methods:

```
this["myMC"]["stop"]();
```

I tried to do that with constructors and i "Failed"  :(

I try to make variables but
This code does NOT work:

```
this["mySprite"]=new ["Sprite"](); Error:Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
```

or

```
this["mySprite"]=new ["Sprite()"]; Error:Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
```

or

```
this["mySprite"]=["new Sprite"](); Error:Value is not a function.
```

or

```
this["mySprite"]=["new Sprite()"]; Error:a term is undefined and has no properties
```

None of them work

Maybe you wonder why i want that:

I want to make new variables at runtime:

```
this[tf1.text]=new [tf2.text]();
```

tf1.text is my variable's name and tf2.text is my constructor.
then I set properties and methods of my variable at runtime(you know how).

I appreciate helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getDefinitionByName() to get the class from a string, then create a new object from that class.

This is an example for getting the Sprite class from a string.

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

var aClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("flash.display.Sprite") as Class;
var sprite:Sprite = new aClass();
```

Comment: I appreciate you for your great answer.just one thing. isn't anyway to skip package name and just write the class name?I removed "flash.display." from this code and it didn't work.And if no way ,that's still good.

Comment: Yes, you can skip the package name if your class is in the same package. I was just using it as an example as the Sprite class was in that package.